# Style Only One Column's Cells DataGrid C# WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, datagrid

I currently style a `DataGridRow` based on the value of a column. The style looks like this;

```
<DataGrid.RowStyle>
    <Style TargetType="DataGridRow">
        <Style.Triggers>
            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Overdue}" Value="1">
                <Setter Property="FontWeight" Value="Bold"/>
            </DataTrigger>
            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Priority}" Value="High">
                <Setter Property="Background" Value="Red"/>
            </DataTrigger>
            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Priority}" Value="Medium">
                <Setter Property="Background" Value="Orange"/>
            </DataTrigger>
            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Priority}" Value="Low">
                <Setter Property="Background" Value="LightGreen"/>
            </DataTrigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
</DataGrid.RowStyle>
```

This applies the style to the entire row based on the column's values. Now however I would to apply the style to only the columns in that cell. This is what the style currently looks like;

[image]

However I would like to remove the styling in the cells with a line through below;

[image]

i.e. only apply the formatting to the priority column's cells rather than the whole row.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try CellStyle for DataGridTemplateColumns.
[Ref.](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc189163.aspx)

Like,
Add the following style "DGCellStyle" in the resource.

```
    <Style x:Key="DGCellStyle" TargetType="DataGridCell">
            <Style.Triggers>
            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Overdue}" Value="1">
                <Setter Property="FontWeight" Value="Bold"/>
            </DataTrigger>
            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Priority}" Value="High">
                <Setter Property="Background" Value="Red"/>
            </DataTrigger>
            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Priority}" Value="Medium">
                <Setter Property="Background" Value="Orange"/>
            </DataTrigger>
            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Priority}" Value="Low">
                <Setter Property="Background" Value="LightGreen"/>
            </DataTrigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
```

Then, refer this style in DataGridTemplateColumn.

```
<DataGridTemplateColumn Header="ColumnHeader" Width="SizeToHeader" CellStyle="{StaticResource DGCellStyle}"/>
```