# DataGrid.CellStyle applies to whole row in C# WPF App

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid, datagridcell

I am currently working on a small c# wpf project. I fill my datagrid programmatically and I want to change one cells color in the style without affecting the whole row. I do this after changing the DataGrid Rowstyle.

```
                   <DataGrid.RowStyle>
                        <Style TargetType="DataGridRow">

                            <Style.Triggers>
                                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=Gebucht}" Value="True">
                                    <Setter Property="Background" Value="Green"/>
                                </DataTrigger>
                                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=dringendeBuchung}" Value="True">
                                    <Setter Property="Background" Value="Yellow"/>
                                </DataTrigger>
                            </Style.Triggers>
                        </Style>
                        
                    </DataGrid.RowStyle>
                    <DataGrid.CellStyle>
                        <Style TargetType="DataGridCell">

                            <Style.Triggers>

                                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=Dringend}" Value="True">
                                    <Setter Property="Background" Value="Red"/>
                                </DataTrigger>
                            </Style.Triggers>
                        </Style>
                    </DataGrid.CellStyle>
```

The rowstyle works fine, but if for example "Gebucht" is true and Dringend is true too I want to display the whole row in green except for the Cell which has the Dringend boolean.

Thank you for your help

Comment: You could have a different style for the cells of the column where you don't want the cells to turn green if Dringend is true as shown in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34943078/13448212)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> The rowstyle works fine, but if for example "Gebucht" is true and Dringend is true too I want to display the whole row in green except for the Cell which has the Dringend boolean.

Then you should set the `CellStyle` property of the specific column instead of setting the `CellStyle` property for the entire `DataGrid`, e.g.:

```
<DataGrid ... >
    <DataGrid.RowStyle>
        <Style TargetType="DataGridRow">
            <Style.Triggers>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=Gebucht}" Value="True">
                    <Setter Property="Background" Value="Green"/>
                </DataTrigger>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=dringendeBuchung}" Value="True">
                    <Setter Property="Background" Value="Yellow"/>
                </DataTrigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </DataGrid.RowStyle>
    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Dringend}" Header="Dringend">
            <DataGridTextColumn.CellStyle>
                <Style TargetType="DataGridCell">
                    <Style.Triggers>
                        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=Dringend}" Value="True">
                            <Setter Property="Background" Value="Red"/>
                        </DataTrigger>
                    </Style.Triggers>
                </Style>
            </DataGridTextColumn.CellStyle>
        </DataGridTextColumn>
        <!-- + other columns... -->
    </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

Comment: Ok, this gets me further than my approach, but now I have two columns with the header "Dringend" and only one of them gets colored in. Is there any way to do this for generated columns? The Binding for the Rows works even if the rows don't exist yet on program start.